# How to make images stack on top of each other, while not affecting the parent element

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

I have this code that that creates a HTML code that shows a Card. Inside the card, there is a Image, Title, Price, Location, and Description. And if you click on the card, it links you to a specific website.

And in some cards, there are multiple images.
But the problem is that, if there are multiple images, it just line up vertically.
When I try `position: absolute;`, it did stack the images on top of each other.
BUT, it also stack the Title, Price, Location, and Description.

Django template HTML:

```
{% for info in post %}
        <a class="link_to_detail" href="{{ info.5 }}">
          <div class="card">
            {{ info.0|safe }}
            <div class="description">
              <h3>{{ info.1 }}</h3>
              <p>{{ info.2 }}</p>
              <p><strong>{{ info.3 }}</strong></p>
              <p>{{ info.4|truncatechars:150 }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
{% endfor %}
```

My views.py on Images (I am new to programming..):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


for li_tag in li_tags:
    first_a_tag = li_tag.find('a')
    detail_page_url = first_a_tag.get("href")
    detail_response = requests.get(detail_page_url)
    detail_src = detail_response.text
    detail_soup = BeautifulSoup(detail_src, 'lxml')

    if first_a_tag.get("data-ids") and isinstance(first_a_tag.get("data-ids").split(','), list):
        post_image_list = first_a_tag.get("data-ids").split(',')
        post_image_setup = []
        post_image_process = first_a_tag.get("data-ids").split(',')
        for images in post_image_process:
        post_image_setup.append('<img src="' + BASE_IMAGE_URL.format(images.split(':')[1]) + '" class="image">')
        post_image_setup.reverse()
        post_image_combine = ''.join(post_image_setup)
        post_image = '<div class="images slides">' + post_image_combine + '</div>'


    elif first_a_tag.get("data-ids") and isinstance(first_a_tag.get("data-ids"), str):
        post_image = '<div class=images><img src=' + BASE_IMAGE_URL.format(first_a_tag.get("data-ids").split(',')[0].split(':')[1]) + ' class=image></div>'

    else:
        post_image = '<div class="images"><img src="https://www.quantabiodesign.com/wp-content/uploads/No-Photo-Available-768x960.jpg"></div>'
```

[What it does when I do `position: absolute; (left and right) (middle one is what I want to happen)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN5Iz.png)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)